# Deploy Windows Applications with Visual Studio.NET

Tags: c#

I have created a window setup file for my window project in visual studio 2008. This setup file is running properly and installed the software in computer. But I want to add a external `exe` file into my setup project. But this external `exe` should not be installed on computer. How can I add this another `exe` file in my setup not for installing?

Comment: you want to add a file to your installation process you mean to be placed in the appliction folder on program files for example.

Comment: Why do you want to add a file to your install project, yet you don't want this file to be installed?

Comment: i have added the file(external exe) but this file also installed on my computer. i don't want this. My main program will use this exe.

Comment: @StaWho actually this exe is a USB driver setup. In my application, it depends on user whether he wants to install USB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is relatively easy, follow these steps and you will be on:

1. Add new setup project (if you already have one, disregard this step)
2. Click on the setup project, then on the left panel select the application folder.
3. right click the application folder --> Add --> File.
4. Select the file you want to install with your setup.
5. you can choose in the application folder properties whether to always create this folder and its files or not.

That it :)

Comment: i don't want to install the file with setup.

Comment: i want to placed external exe in the appliction folder.I have followed you steps.But this exe also installed with main exe during installaion. actually this external exe is a USB driver setup. In my application, it depends on user whether he wants to install USB Driver